# Using subscribe on a GroupedObservable in map

Tags: rxjs

I have an array of objects like the follwing:

```
private questions: Question[] = [
    {
        title: "...",
        category: "Technologie",
        answer: `...`
    },
    {
        title: "...",
        category: "Technologie",
        answer: `...`
    },
    {
        title: "...",
        category: "eID",
        answer: `...`
    }
];
```

And I would like to group them by categories, filter them based on a value and return the result as an array. Currently, I'm using this:

```
Observable
    .from(this.questions)
    .groupBy(q => q.category)
    .map(go => 
    {
        let category: Category = { title: go.key, questions: [] };

        go.subscribe(d => category.questions.push(d));

        return category;
    })
    .filter(c =>  c.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0 || c.questions.filter(q => q.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0).length > 0)
    .toArray()
```

This finds the question with the value in the category title but not the one with the value in the question title. I think that's because I'm using a `subscribe` in `map`, therefore, the questions are not yet available in the `filter` method, so I was wondering if there's a possibility to wait for the `subscribe` to end before going into `filter`. My research pointed me to `flatMap` but I can't get it to do what I want.

**EDIT**

I figured out that I can fix the issue like this:

```
Observable
    .from(this.questions)
    .filter(q =>  q.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0 || q.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
    .groupBy(q => q.category)
    .map(go => 
    {
        let category: Category = { title: go.key, questions: [] };

        go.subscribe(d => category.questions.push(d));

        return category;
    })            
    .toArray()
```

But I'm still interested in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you use groupBy, you get a grouped observable that can be flattened with operators like concatMap, mergeMap, switchMap etc. Within those operators, grouped observables can be transformed separately for each category, i.e. collect the questions together into an array with reduce, and then create the desired object with map.

```
   Observable
        .from(questions)
        .groupBy(q => q.category)
        .mergeMap(go => {
            return go.reduce((acc, question) => { acc.push(question); return acc; }, [])
                .map(questions => ({ title: go.key, questions }));
        })
        .filter(c => "...")
        .toArray()
```