# Rxjs 6, GroupBy with a single emit

Tags: rxjs

If I have the following data

```
[
    { person: 'john', age: 12 },
    { person: 'abby', age: 12 },
    { person: 'kyle', age: 14 },
]
```

And I would like the following result

```
[
    [
        { person: 'john', age: 12 },
        { person: 'abby', age: 12 }
    ],
    [
        { person: 'kyle', age: 14 }
    ]
]
```

What would be the correct rxjs expression? I currently have

```
const grouped = source.pipe(
    groupBy(person => person.age),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))
);
```

However that outputs twice which is messing up my rendering in Angular as I want to render all the results.

```
// First emit
[
    { person: 'john', age: 12 },
    { person: 'abby', age: 12 }
]
// Second emit
[
    { person: 'kyle', age: 14 }
]
```

---

Edit: If possible I would also like to see how to transform the object.

Example output

```
[
    [
        age: 12,
        people: [
            { person: 'john', age: 12 },
            { person: 'abby', age: 12 }
        ]
    ],
    [
        age: 14,
        people: [
            { person: 'kyle', age: 14 }
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand what RxJs functions do and what the RxJs map function does. RxJs functions apply to the stream, if you want to manipulate a single value that comes down the stream you need to use map to apply a function to the item that was emitted. You need a groupBy function that works with arrays, not streams.

```
groupBy(person => person.age)
```

This line in your code is not receiving a person, it is receiving an array of people.

You need to

```
const grouped = source.pipe(
  map(people => groupBy(people, { keys: ['age'] }))
);
```

This observable will emit a grouped object. Where will you find a function that groups arrays? I have written one here https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez/blob/master/projects/ngx-ez/src/lib/ez-core/functions/group-by.ts with a demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-iwuzkw?file=group-by.ts but the shape of the object is not quite what you want.

```
[
    [
        key: { age: 12 },
        items: [
            { person: 'john' },
            { person: 'abby' }
        ]
    ],
    [
        key: { age: 14 },
        items: [
            { person: 'kyle' }
        ]
    ]
]
```

But should be usable in the way you want.

It could definitely be simplified for your purposes as you don't need sum and then by functionality but it is a starting point.

The function is exported from my library Easy Angular, "npm install ngx-ez" and then you could just import it with

```
import { groupBy } from 'ngx-ez';
```

If you are not using Angular you could ignore the angular dependencies as that function doesn't require Angular.

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { map } = rxjs.operators;

const source$ = of([
    { person: 'john', age: 12 },
    { person: 'abby', age: 12 },
    { person: 'kyle', age: 14 },
]);

const sumGroup = (group, sum) => {
  if (!sum || !sum.length || !group) {
    return group;
  }
  return {
    ...group,
    sum: sum.reduce(
      (sumObj, sumProp) => ({
        ...sumObj,
        [sumProp]: group.items.reduce((a, b) => resolveProperty(a, sumProp) + resolveProperty(b, sumProp))
      }),
      {}
    )
  };
};

const groupBy = (array, grouping) => {
  if (!array) {
    return array;
  }
  const keys = grouping.keys;
  const groups = array.reduce((results, item) => {
    const group = results.find(g => keys.every(key => item[key] === g.key[key]));
    const data = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item).reduce((o, prop) => {
      if (!keys.some(key => key === prop)) {
        o[prop] = item[prop];
      }
      return o;
    }, {});
    if (group) {
      group.items.push(data);
    } else {
      results.push({
        key: keys.reduce((o, key) => {
          o[key] = item[key];
          return o;
        }, {}),
        items: [data]
      });
    }
    return results;
  }, []);
  return grouping.thenby
    ? groups.map(g => ({ ...g, items: groupBy(g.items, grouping.thenby) }))
    : groups.reduce((arr, g) => {
        arr.push(sumGroup(g, grouping.sum));
        return arr;
      }, []);
};

const grouped$ = source$.pipe(map(people => groupBy(people, { keys: ['age'] })));

grouped$.subscribe(grouped => { console.log(grouped); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RxJS Observables you can solve it this way

```
    import { from, of, zip } from 'rxjs';
    import { groupBy, mergeMap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

    interface IPerson {
      name: string;
      age: number;
    }

    const people: IPerson[] = [
      { name: 'Sue', age: 25 },
      { name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
      { name: 'Frank', age: 25 },
      { name: 'Sarah', age: 35 },
    ];

    from(people)
      .pipe(
        groupBy(
          (person) => person.age,
      (p) => p
    ),
    mergeMap((group) => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray()))),
    toArray()
  )
  .subscribe((res) => console.log(JSON.stringify(res)));
```

Output

```
    [
        [25,[{"name":"Sue","age":25},{"name":"Frank","age":25}]],
        [30,[{"name":"Joe","age":30}]],
        [35,[{"name":"Sarah","age":35}]]
    ]
```

The stackblitz link is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-groupby-key-vals-mbcfxn?file=index.ts)

Additional resources

- https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/groupby
- [Using subscribe on a GroupedObservable in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670839/using-subscribe-on-a-groupedobservable-in-map)